# Explicit calculation of Bala-Carter correspondence

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

I am wondering where can I find examples of explicit calculation of Bala-Carter correspondence for algebraic groups of classical types of small ranks.

Would you please give me some clues?

Thank you very much!